# moist_lapse has error "IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable." and has no reason it should

Tags: python, metpy

I am using both dry_lapse and moist_lapse to try and find the showalter index of a dataset. I was able to get dry_lapse to run successfully and wanted to use the temperature output of dry in the moist_lapse function. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
# Stability
dl = mpcalc.dry_lapse(p[2], tac[0], p[0])
dl = (dl.magnitude - 273.15)*units.degC # Change units to C

ml = mpcalc.moist_lapse(p[11], dl, p[2])
```

where p is pressure levels from the data and tac is is parcel profile temp in degC.

What the code is meant to do is calculate the parcel temp if it was lifted dry adiabatically from p[0] (1008mb) to the lcl level at p[2] (950mb), then calculate the parcel temp if it was then lifted moist adiabatically from p[2] to [p11] (500mb level). I have checked the values I'm using in moist_lapse by replacing them with the values used in dry_lapse but the error does not resolve. I'm not sure if the error is from something wrong in the function source code, or if I am overlooking an error in my inputs for either dry or moist lapse.

Comment: You should add the error stack that got generated and identify which line above it pointed to.  this will hep folks respond.   The exception is telling you that something is trying to apply a index value to something that is not an array.  The exception trace will help us better answer your question.

Comment: What version of MetPy are you using? This looks like an issue that may have been resolved in v1.0 (with this PR: https://github.com/Unidata/MetPy/pull/1579). To confirm, try wrapping your initial pressure argument with `np.atleast_1d()`. Otherwise, feel free to try using MetPy's `parcel_profile` function to obtain your parcel temperature at 500 mb to compute SI.

Comment: @JonThielen I updated my version to the most recent and tried to run the code again and it did work this time. Thank you for that pointer!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was from using an older version of MetPy, this was resolved by updated my version locally.